# 'std::string' has no member named 'get' list[i]=user.get;

Tags: c++, string, char

I get this error in my code and I know why it's there. But I don't now how to fix it and achieve what I want to achieve.
        list[i]=user.get; << this line of code is me trying to put a string into a char array. How would I convert the string into char while still being able to keep user.length() and getline so I can know how big my dynamic array should be?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char *list;
string user;
int counter[26];
int data;
cout<< "Enter in a line of text (all lowercase)"<<endl;
//cin>>user;
getline(cin, user);
//cin.get(user);
cout<< user.length()<<endl;
list = new char [user.length()];
for(int i=0; i<user.length(); i++)
{
    list[i]=user.get;
}
cout<< list[0]<<endl;
/*
char alphabet [26];
for (int i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    data=i+97;
    alphabet[i]=data;
    cout<< data;
} 

for (int i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    if (list[i]==alphabet[i])
    counter[i]++;
    cout<< list[0];
}
*/
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the string documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

The [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method returns a pointer to the underlying char array that you can `memcpy` or `strcpy` into a char array of your own.

```
std::size_t user_length = user.length() + 1;
char* list = new char [user_length];
strncpy(list, user.c_str(), user_length);    
...
delete [] list;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
list[i]=user.get;
```

With

```
list[i]=user.at(i);
```